# Using ELCImagePickerController to select images

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use the `ELCImagePickerController` , and it works but i have a few things that i would like to change .

1. i want it to show me a matrix of images from the main album right away, without picking albums and stuff. just show a matrix, with a `done` button . now it lets you pick an album first .
2. i cant understand where exactly the picked images where saved ?
3. how can i change the buttons `cancel` and `done` graphics ?

this is how i add it (to cocos2d scene )

```
 albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ELCAlbumPickerController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
       elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
       [albumController setParent:elcPicker];
       [elcPicker setDelegate:self];
       [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:elcPicker.view];
```

this is the done button :

```
- (void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info



{
    //[self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];


    for (UIView *v in [scrollview subviews])
    {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect workingFrame = scrollview.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    for(NSDictionary *dict in info)
    {

        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        imageview.frame = workingFrame;

        [scrollview addSubview:imageview];
        [imageview release];

        workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
    }

    [scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: no one did that before ???

Comment: any direction ? i am just lost with it ..